# Dropping unsigned index foreign key in laravel. Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP; check that column/key exists

Tags: php, laravel-5, database-migration

I created migration using the following

```
Schema::table('packages', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->integer('star_id')->unsigned()->index()->nullable()->default(null);
     $table->foreign('star_id')->references('id')->on('star');
});
```

in drop part

```
Schema::table('packages', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->dropForeign('star_id');
      //$table->dropIndex('star_id'); //also tried dropIndex
      $table->dropColumn('star_id');
 });
```

but it throws for index and foreign

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1553 Cannot drop index
>   'packages_star_id_index': needed in a foreign key constraint (SQL:
>   alter table `packages` drop `star_id`)

error for dropForeign

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP
>   'star_id'; check that column/key exists (SQL: alter table `packages`
>   drop foreign key `star_id`)

I cannot rollback because of the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the foreign key name yourself or pass the column name in an array for laravel to automatically build it.

See [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php#L1300):

> If the given "index" is actually an array of columns, the developer
>   means to drop an index merely by specifying the columns involved
>   without the conventional name, so we will build the index name from
>   the columns.

```php
// laravel assumes star_id is the foreign key name
$table->dropForeign('star_id'); 

// laravel builds the foreign key name itself e.g. packages_star_id_foreign
$table->dropForeign(['star_id']);
```

So in your case just pass the column in an array:

```php
Schema::table('packages', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropForeign(['star_id']);
    $table->dropColumn('star_id');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> Blockquote
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1553 Cannot drop index 'packages_star_id_index': needed in a foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table packages drop star_id)

As per your error, index name was "packages_star_id_index".
you should mention the proper index name in dropForeign function.

give it a try:

```
Schema::table('packages', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->dropForeign('packages_star_id_index');
      $table->dropColumn('star_id');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Laravel 7 documentation, for dropping foreign key
this code will work:

```
$table->dropForeign('posts_user_id_foreign');
```

in which "posts" is the table name, "user_id" is foreign key name and "foreign" is the suffix.

There is also another method that only pass foreign key name in an array like this:

```
$table->dropForeign(['user_id']);
```

this picture is from Laravel website (v 7.x):
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taQqM.png)